# Is possible create a Core in appcelerator for ios and android

Tags: android, ios, appcelerator

I need to create a large enterprise application and I wonder if it is possible to create a common core with Appcelerator as a "framework" for iPhone and Android. The idea is to start the project in native to maximize the view of each platform but the common part of the application and make it strong with Appcelerator.

Comment: To make the most native views when creating the application for each platform the idea is to create a project to start in xcode. Let's say we create the view with Interface Builder but all the functionality that may exist behind, login, web services, all of which could be common across platforms create with Appcelerator. Once finished this draft say we started doing the android and do the same views but we add the module created with Appcelerator and this part and this common for both platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this strategy would work. From what I know af Appcelerator it doesn't generate code that represents your javascript for each platform. It generates a rending engine that then interprets your javascript on the fly.

So I don't think you could write majority of your app is native and then just tie in some Appcelerator elements.  You can go the other way.. where you create the core project in Appcelerator than pull in some other libraries which could be your native views.. but Appcelerator would be your core and then pull in those other items specific to each platform.